# Injectivity radius and complete manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.
$M$ is called complete, if the maximal geodesics on $M$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

The injectivity radius of a point in $M$ is the largest radius, s.t. the exponential map is a diffeomorphism.

The injectivity radius of $M$ is the infimum of the injectivity radii of all points.

Now in some sources, I have read that completeness and non-zero injectivity radius are equivalent conditions, while in other sources, it says that completeness implies non-zero injectivity radius (but not vice versa).

I however don't really see an obvious connection between these two definitions..

Comment: Yes, these conditions are not equivalent, but it is easy to see that positive injectivity radius implies completeness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Example.** The set $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ described by the equation $x^2+y^2=e^{-z}$ is a $2$-dimensional submanifold. It's complete, but the injectivity radius is $0$, as can be seen by looking at the circles $z = \mathrm{const}$ (and large), which get arbitrarily small.

---

Using the definition you provided, you should be able to show that positive injectivity radius implies completeness. If this radius is $r>0$, one can extend any finite geodesic at least by $r/2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the example! What I don't quite understand yet is that in some sources it says something like "Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold with positive injectivity radius." Do I see it right that it is not necessary to mention completeness here?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would guess that completeness is always mentioned since it's fundamental. That is, we first state that we're working in the category of complete manifolds, and then add the additional assumptions (like positive injectivity radius).